# Can ElasticSearch choose one of include field that is not empty or not null?

Tags: elasticsearch

If I have three include field, [result1, result2, result3] Can ElasticSearch return that is not empty or not null field?

I mean not in the query filter, is there source or include filter in Elasticsearch?

Comment: Well would be easy if you shared a mapping but take a look at Exists query:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Say, to get all documents which has result2 as null **AND** result1 not null, you can use the following query:

```
{
  "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "exists": {
                  "field": "result1"
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                  "must_not": {
                      "exists": {
                          "field": "result2"
                      }
                  }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
    }
}
```

To get documents which has result2 as null **OR** result1 not null, wrap the exist condition queries around ***should*** and then wrap around bool.